# An issue with np.nan when using it to replace all elements of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

Here is an 1D array:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

I am trying to replace all elements with `np.nan`. Naturally, I would try:

```
a[:] = np.nan
```

which ended up returning:

```
array([-9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808])
```

So the question is simply: why does it not work.

P.S. Currently I am just using

```
a = np.array([np.nan for a_i in a])
```

to achieve what I wanted to do.

Comment: `np.full_like(a, np.nan, dtype=float)` works also

Comment: The truth is this is a bug in NumPy. By default, NumPy tries to convert any assigned values to the array type. So if you did `a[:] =1.3` you would just get an array of ones, because `a` type is integer. However, there is no well-defined conversion from `np.nan` to integer, and in fact `a[0] = np.nan` fails, but it seems that the slice assignment operation does not perform this check correctly.

Comment: @jdehesa np.iinfo(np.int64)  ==> 
iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64) ... so it isn't a bug, it is an attempt to return something associated with the appropriate integer dtype that might be considered nodata

Comment: @NaN It is a bug because the behavior is different depending on whether it is a single-element assignment or a slice assignment. They could decide that the correct behavior is to always fail or to always convert to the minimum value, but it should be consistent in all cases.

Comment: Actually it is already a reported issue: [Nan are converted to int with slicing #4592](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4592)

Comment: @scleronomic strangely, `np.full(len(a), np.nan)` works without needing to specify dtype

Comment: @cssstudent this is because `np.full_like(a)` copys the `dtype` of `a` when constructing the new array (when no other `dtype` is given) and `np.full(len(a))` uses the default `dtype` (which is float) when constructing the new array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is being created with `dtype='int64'`. If you create you array as an array of floats it will work.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=float)
a[:] = np.nan
print(a)
```

will give

```
[nan nan nan]
```

alternatively you could create your array using at least one float in your initial list (but better to be explicit)

```
a = np.array([1., 2, 3])
a[:] = np.nan
print(a)
```

gives

```
[nan nan nan]
```